# Java program opens PDF with Microsoft Word

Tags: windows, java, pdf-reader

Some workmates have to use an online application which is Java powered, so they use Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Within the Java program, some menu entries open PDF documents. On all but one computer the PDF documents open with Adobe Reader and everything is ok.

On ONE computer (Windows 8.1) the PDF open with Microsoft Word only from the Java program.
But the file association is ok: if we double-clic on a random PDF, it opens correctly with Adobe Reader. If we run `rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler test.pdf` it opens correctly with Adobe Reader. If I check files associations in the control panel, the PDF familly seem ok. If Internet Explorer is directed to a PDF page, it is correctly displayed inside Internet Explorer (this is not what we want ultimatly, but this is a good start).

The browser run `jp2launcher.exe` which display the online application's UI is a separate Window. `jp2launcher.exe` in turn run Adobe Reader when needed (or Microsoft Word erroneously).

--> does someone know the source of this problem ? And/or a way to solve it?

edit for JRI: when a website send a PDF, it is displayed inside Internet Explorer

edit for Bertrand SCHITS: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" https://example.com/reports/rwservlet/getjobidxxxxx?server=rep_wls_reports_xxxxxxxxx` and similar command line when running Adobe reader

Comment: Do any of the working machines also use Win 8.1?

Comment: When you mention double-clicking, I assume you mean a local file in Windows Explorer or your desktop. 
 On the broken machine, what happens if you try to open a PDF file from a website using Internet Explorer?  (Without using the java app).

Comment: On a well behaving computer, what is the command line to launch the PDF? On the faulty computer, does another user account exhibit the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be the `URL:Accrobat Document` file association (or more exactly protocole association) which is broken.
You should have a look at this in the file associations applet.

Comment: The "URL" association was unchecked. I just checked it for Acrobat Reader and the problem is solved in less than 30 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's clear the Java program doesn't open the PDF using the Windows mechanism. Knowing that jp2launcher is called is not helpful, as it is only the
launcher for the java program, nothing else.

As this problem only concerns this Java program on this one computer,
we need more information about this program.

Without such information, all I can suggest is to uninstall it and Java,
using Revo to uninstall, scrub the disk and registry for all remnants,
then reinstall Java and the program.